# How to create in Golang dynamic bson for mongo DB $match

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a trouble when I try to write BSON for MongoDB, especially when try to create dynamic bson. Here's my query in MongoDB.

```
db.fee_report.aggregate(
    [ 
        { $match : { client_id : 2 } },
        { $match : { trx_type : "Close Payment" } },
        { $match: { execution_date: {$gte: "2021-02-01", $lte: "2021-02-06"} } },
    ]
);
```

Here is my example request:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "max_rows": 20,
    "order_by": "created_at",
    "order_type": "asc",
    "date_range": {
        "from": "2021-02-01",
        "to": "2021-02-02"
    },
    "search": [
        {
            "column": "client_id",
            "value": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please see at date_range and search field, because this fields are dynamic.

```
{ $match : { client_id : 2 } },
{ $match : { trx_type : "Close Payment" } },
{ $match: { execution_date: {$gte: "2021-02-01", $lte: "2021-02-06"} } },
```

Example, sometimes we dont send client_id and it should be

```
{ $match : { trx_type : "Close Payment" } },
{ $match: { execution_date: {$gte: "2021-02-01", $lte: "2021-02-06"} } },
```

Here's my code in Go. I get trouble when trying to passing dynaminc BSON for this.

```
func AggregateToMongo(d constant.DateRange, c ...constant.Search) bson.M {
    filter := bson.M{}

    if d != (constant.DateRange{}) {
        filter["execution_date"] = map[string]interface{}{
            "$gt": d.From,
            "$lt": d.To,
        }
    }

    for _, n := range c {
        if n.Params != "" {
            filter[n.ColumnName] = n.Params
        }
    }

    vr := bson.M{}

    for v, i := range filter {
        vr[v] = i
    }

    return bson.M{
        "$match": vr,
    }
}
```

I get an error after that. Please somebody help me. And I will appreciate if anybody can help me to solve this. I get stuck with this more than 8 hours.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
func AggregateToMongo(d constant.DateRange, c ...constant.Search) bson.M {
    dr := bson.M{}
    if d != (constant.DateRange{}) {
        dr = bson.M{"execution_date": bson.M{
            "$gte": d.From, "$lte": d.To},
        }
    }

    p := bson.M{}
    for _, n := range c {
        if n.Params != "" {
            if n.ColumnName == "client_id" {
                i, err := strconv.ParseInt(n.Params, 10, 32)
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
                p = bson.M{n.ColumnName: i}
            } else {
                p = bson.M{n.ColumnName: n.Params}
            }
        }
    }

    filter := bson.M{
        "$match": bson.M{
            "$and": []bson.M{dr, p},
        },
    }

    return filter
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i have same problem too and this is help so much.

Comment: vr[v] = i this code works for me